# How to optimize batch forecasting

Tags: r, data.table, forecasting

I came across Joseph Owen code [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/batch-forecasting-r-redux-joseph-owens/) for batch forecasting. I have a dataset containing close to ~19k rows but the issue is even with the batch forecasting methodology applied my code still runs super slow.

I need to evaluate the best model for which I am using MAPE as the evaluating criteria before doing the actual forecast. Below is the workable code snippet for the same. My question is how to optimize the below code to make it run in the acceptable time  (under 2 mins)

```
 fcnChooseETS <- function(Ts){
       
  TsPositive <- ( min( as.numeric(Ts) ) > 0 ) # Check if all values of timeseries are positive or not
  
  ModelsUsed <- c("ANN","MNN","ANA","AAN","AAA","MAA","MNM","MMN","MMM","MNA","MAN","MAM")
  ModelsNonPositive <- c("ANN","ANA","AAN","AAA") # Multiplicative models cannot take non positive data
  
  if( !TsPositive ){
    ModelsUsed <- ModelsNonPositive
  }
  
  lAllModels <- lapply(ModelsUsed, function(M){
    ets(Ts, damped = NULL, model = M)
  })
  
  vecResult <- sapply(lAllModels, function(M) accuracy(M)[2])
  
  names(vecResult) <- ModelsUsed
  min(vecResult)      
}  

    fcnTrending <- function( dt){
      Ts <- lapply(transpose(dt), ts , frequency = 12 , end = FeedDate)
      fit <- lapply(Ts , fcnChooseETS ) 
    }
```

Comment: What operating system are you on? You *may* see an advantage switching out `lapply()` with a parallel analog depending on your OS and machine. I have not used parallel processing to run models before, but it is the only other option I could think of. Like @Rui said, your bottleneck is almost certainly with `ets()`

Answer (score 3):

The following script tests 3 different ways of fitting the models in the question. The first of them is a more idiomatic version of the code posted in the question, the next two fit the several models in parallel.

This script was saved in file `so_62497397.R` and run as below.

```
#
# filename: so_62497397.R
# Test serial and two types of parallel execution of
# exponential smoothing time series fitting.

library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(forecast)

fcnChooseETS <- function(Ts){

  TsPositive <- ( min( as.numeric(Ts) ) > 0 ) # Check if all values of timeseries are positive or not

  ModelsUsed <- c("ANN","MNN","ANA","AAN","AAA","MAA","MNM","MMN","MMM","MNA","MAN","MAM")
  ModelsNonPositive <- c("ANN","ANA","AAN","AAA") # Multiplicative models cannot take non positive data

  if( !TsPositive ){
    ModelsUsed <- ModelsNonPositive
  }

  lAllModels <- lapply(ModelsUsed, function(M){
    ets(Ts, damped = NULL, model = M)
  })

  vecResult <- sapply(lAllModels, function(M) accuracy(M)[2])

  names(vecResult) <- ModelsUsed
  vecResult[which.min(vecResult)]
}
fcnChooseETS2 <- function(Ts, Ncpus = 2){

  TsPositive <- ( min( as.numeric(Ts) ) > 0 ) # Check if all values of timeseries are positive or not

  ModelsUsed <- c("ANN","MNN","ANA","AAN","AAA","MAA","MNM","MMN","MMM","MNA","MAN","MAM")
  ModelsNonPositive <- c("ANN","ANA","AAN","AAA") # Multiplicative models cannot take non positive data

  if( !TsPositive ){
    ModelsUsed <- ModelsNonPositive
  }

  vecResult <- mclapply(ModelsUsed, function(M){
    fit <- ets(Ts, damped = NULL, model = M)
    accuracy(fit)[2]
  }, mc.cores = Ncpus)

  vecResult <- unlist(vecResult)
  names(vecResult) <- ModelsUsed
  vecResult[which.min(vecResult)]
}

fcnChooseETS3 <- function(Ts, Ncpus = 2){

  TsPositive <- ( min( as.numeric(Ts) ) > 0 ) # Check if all values of timeseries are positive or not

  ModelsUsed <- c("ANN","MNN","ANA","AAN","AAA","MAA","MNM","MMN","MMM","MNA","MAN","MAM")
  ModelsNonPositive <- c("ANN","ANA","AAN","AAA") # Multiplicative models cannot take non positive data

  if( !TsPositive ){
    ModelsUsed <- ModelsNonPositive
  }

  cl <- makeCluster(Ncpus)
  clusterExport(cl, 'ts')
  clusterEvalQ(cl, library(forecast))
  vecResult <- parLapply(cl, ModelsUsed, function(M){
    fit <- ets(Ts, damped = NULL, model = M)
    accuracy(fit)[2]
  })
  stopCluster(cl)

  vecResult <- unlist(vecResult)
  names(vecResult) <- ModelsUsed
  vecResult[which.min(vecResult)]
}

makeTestdata <- function(N){
  n <- length(USAccDeaths)
  m <- ceiling(log2(N/n))
  x <- as.numeric(USAccDeaths)
  for(i in seq_len(m)) x <- c(x, x)
  L <- length(x)/12 - 1
  x <- ts(x, start = 2000 - L, frequency = 12)
  x
}


numCores <- detectCores()
cat("numCores:", numCores, "\n")

x <- makeTestdata(5e3)

t1 <- system.time(
  res1 <- fcnChooseETS(x)
)
t2 <- system.time(
  res2 <- fcnChooseETS2(x, Ncpus = numCores)
)
t3 <- system.time(
  res3 <- fcnChooseETS3(x, Ncpus = numCores)
)

rbind(t.lapply = t1,
      t.mclapply = t2,
      t.parLapply = t3)

c(res1, res2, res3)
```

---

Run with `Rscript` on

- an aging PC, processor Intel® Core™ i3 CPU 540 @ 3.07GHz × 4 cores,
- R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
- Ubuntu 20.04.

The timings show that `mclapply` is the best option, though not much faster than `parLapply`. Of the fitted models, the chosen using MAPE are all the same, as they should be.

```
rui@rui:~$ Rscript --vanilla so_62497397.R
#Loading required package: iterators
#Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#  method            from
#  as.zoo.data.frame zoo 
#numCores: 4 
#            user.self sys.self elapsed user.child sys.child
#t.lapply       56.505    0.063  57.389      0.000      0.00
#t.mclapply      0.039    0.024  33.983     30.506      0.26
#t.parLapply     0.040    0.012  36.317      0.001      0.00
#     ANA      ANA      ANA 
#263.0876 263.0876 263.0876
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, I was using the same method using lapply instead of individual statements but even then the execution time is really high.

Comment: @RohitSaluja The time must go to `ets`. And if you are fitting so many models, then there is no solution but to wait.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, just an option. You could swap out `lapply()` for the models with `sapply()` with `simplify = FALSE` and skip the renaming.